# Sails.js Socket.IO getting data with a time frame window (setInterval)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

Hello i'm starting to use socket.io with sails.js and I would like to know if there is a way or a best practice to get the data that socket.emit (in my controller) sends each time, not just once.. I tried to use socket.get but when I print the values in the console they appear only once.

I'm gonna use this in a future to push data to the client to track the status of an item that I get from a REST interface in a different project.

Controller Code

```
my_event: function(req, res){
    var socket = req.socket;
    setInterval(function(){
      socket.emit('my_event', { content: 'data' })
    }, 5000)
  }
```

Client Side Code

```
var c = 0;
socket.get('/mycontroller/my_event',  function (json) {
    c = c++;        
    console.log(json.content);
    console.log(c);

});
```

I saw in the network tab (chrome console) that I'm getting the data with the correct time intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering the `my_event` action to start the `setInterval` and its recurring `socket.emit`, but you're never listening for the event on the client side.  What you need is:

```
var c = 0;
// Bind a listener to the "my_event' socket event
socket.on('my_event', function(json) {
    c = c++;        
    console.log(json.content);
    console.log(c);
});
// Call the backend action which will start triggering the events
socket.get('/mycontroller/my_event',  function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

then on the server inside `my_event`, make sure you end it with something like

```
res.json({status: 'ok!'});
```

if you want to tell that the `socket.get` call was successful.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to try that, so the event was fired but I didn't had a listener for it :/